# how to change backgraound color of cells in datatable in react Js based on conditions?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, background-color

I created the below data table.

[image]

I need to change the background color of the cells (if there is any value), except for the "Net Lost" and "Net Recovered" columns. If there are any values including the first value of the array (each sub-array in `rawData` in the below code-snippet), then it should be red and all values except "Net Lost" and "Net Recovered" should be green.

Desired Output:

[image]

Code to get the datatable:

```js
    import { useState } from "react";
    
     export default function DataTable1(){
    
     const rawData= [[7,'',2,1,4,3],[8,3,'',5,3],['','','',''],[4,4,'']]
     
     return (
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th>Week 1</th>
              <th>Week 2</th>
              <th>Week 3</th>
              <th>Week 4</th>
              <th>Net Lost</th>
              <th>Net Recovered</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {rawData.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <tr>
                  <th>Week {index + 1}</th>
                  {[...Array(6 - item.length)].map((item) => {
                    return <td></td>;  //for empty values
                  })}
                  {item.map((itm) => {
                    return <td>{itm}</td>;
                  })}
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      );
       
    }
```

I know how to change the background colors using CSS in normal scenarios. But for this I would really appreciate your support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do it with CSS

```css
table, tr, td, th {
  border: .1em solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
  padding: .4em;
}

tbody > tr > td {
  background-color: red;
}

tbody > tr > td:not(:empty) ~ td.data {
  background-color: green;
}

tbody > tr > td:empty,
tbody > tr > td:nth-child(n+6) {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Week 1</th>
      <th>Week 2</th>
      <th>Week 3</th>
      <th>Week 4</th>
      <th>Net Lost</th>
      <th>Net Recovered</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Week 1</th>
        <td class="data">7</td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="data">2</td>
        <td class="data">1</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Week 2</th>
        <td></td>
        <td class="data">8</td>
        <td class="data">3</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Week 3</th>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Week 4</th>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="data">4</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>      
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and without adding a class, can use important

```css
table, tr, td, th {
  border: .1em solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
  padding: .4em;
}

tbody > tr > td {
  background-color: red;
}

tbody > tr > td:not(:empty) ~ td {
  background-color: green;
}

tbody > tr > td:empty,
tbody > tr > td:nth-child(n+6) {
  background-color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Week 1</th>
      <th>Week 2</th>
      <th>Week 3</th>
      <th>Week 4</th>
      <th>Net Lost</th>
      <th>Net Recovered</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Week 1</th>
        <td>7</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Week 2</th>
        <td></td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Week 3</th>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Week 4</th>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>      
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That's some nice CSS. Note OP will have to change the code `return <td>{itm}</td>;` to include the "class=" in the appropriate `<td>` elements.

Comment: This is amazing!!! thanks a lot.  @epascarello can you please explain the CSS part?

Comment: basic css selectors for child and siblings. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/css-selectors-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 1):

Just use a .css file to style the className, and its down.

```
 <tr>
    <th>Week {index + 1}</th>
      {[...Array(6 - items.length)].map((item) => {
        return <td>-</td>; //for empty values
          })}
      {items.map((item, i) => {
         return (
           <>
            {i == 0 && item != "" ? (
              <td className="red">{item}</td>
                ) : index + i < 4 && item != "" ? (
                  <td className="green">{item}</td>
                ) : (
                  <td className="">{item}</td>
                )}{" "}
              </>
            );
     })}
   </tr>
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/6hb4e2?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thanks and it works!!! can we 'remove the black hypens under the diagonal' and add some column and row lines to make it more clear?

Comment: If  I understand correctly you would add in CSS file  `table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid;
}` Codesandbox is now updated

Comment: I'm glad it's working. it would be appreciated if you could choose it as the question's answer.